# Apply Monaco editor to textarea instead of div

Tags: javascript, html, monaco-editor

I have the following textarea in my html-document:
`<textarea id="container"></textarea>`

I used the `monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container')` function to initialise the editor, but it fails, without writing some error to the console. When I change the textarea to div it works fine.

Is it possible to make it work with a textarea instead of a div?

Regards
Andi

Comment: That doesn't really make sense since the editor element is transformed into a complex HTML structure that has no business inside an input. Instead, maybe clone the stringified contents into an input for your purposes.

Comment: I don't think this works the way you're thinking as it probably creates the textarea inside of whatever element you select for the container so you cannot put textarea inside a textarea.

Comment: I wondered about that, too, but couldn't find an input in the rendered HTML. Maybe I missed it.

Comment: Just saw your comment to the answer provided. I wish I would have seen your post a long time ago! You will want to look into either Ace editor or CodeMirror. Perhaps you've already discovered this by now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not** possible to render an instance of `monaco-editor` to a `<textarea>` tag.

### Why?

The `<textarea>` tag is **not** a container; it is a multiline, plain text edit control for the text's raw value. Additionally, the API specified by the `monaco-editor` developers explicitly requires an **[empty container](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#create)**.

#### Additional reference

- [WHATWG textarea specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-textarea-element)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to integrate the editor into an existing application where a textarea is used. Maybe I need to use another solution for this.